# Observable.FromAsyncPattern with UDPClient.EndReceive and ref remote endpoint Parameter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I'm learning about Reactive extensions and trying to re-factor some of my code.

`UDPClient.EndReceive` takes a `ref IPEndPoint` parameter, so I currently have this working:

```
UdpClient receiverUDP = new UdpClient();
receiverUDP.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
receiverUDP.EnableBroadcast = true;
receiverUDP.Client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
receiverUDP.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));

IPEndPoint ep = null;
var async = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[]>(receiverUDP.BeginReceive, (i) => receiverUDP.EndReceive(i, ref ep));
var subscr = async().Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(x)));
```

What if my subscribers need access to the remote IPEndPoint? In my current incarnation I'm using events, and passing back a custom class which wraps `byte[]` and `IPEndPoint`. I cannot for the life of me, work out how to do this with Rx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else looking, there's a slightly simpler, and more modern way to do this using `ReceiveAsync`:

```
public static IObservable<UdpReceiveResult> UdpStream(IPEndPoint endpoint)
{
    return Observable.Using(() => new UdpClient(endpoint),
        udpClient => Observable.Defer(() =>
            udpClient.ReceiveAsync().ToObservable()).Repeat());
}
```

You can call it with IPAddress.Any:

```
var stream = UdpStream(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 514));
```

and then use `Select` to project the stream to whatever type you want.

Answer (score 6):

If you've already created a wrapper class for `byte[]` and `IPEndPoint` why not return that as the sequence using `Select`:

```
private IObservable<RemoteData> GetRemoteDataAsync()
{
    return Observable.Defer(() => 
    {
        UdpClient receiverUDP = new UdpClient();
        receiverUDP.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, 
            SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        receiverUDP.EnableBroadcast = true;
        receiverUDP.Client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        receiverUDP.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1234));

        IPEndPoint ep = null;
        return Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[]>(
                   receiverUDP.BeginReceive, 
                   (i) => receiverUDP.EndReceive(i, ref ep)
               )()
               .Select(bytes => new RemoteData(bytes, ep));
    });
}
```

Comment: 'System.Func<System.IObservable<byte[]>>' does not contain a definition for 'Select'

Comment: Changed to:
                var func = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[]>(
                           receiverUDP.BeginReceive,
                           (i) => receiverUDP.EndReceive(i, ref ep)
                       );

                return func().Select(bytes => new UDPMessage(bytes, ep));