# Testing IObservable 'dispatcher'

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have several different 'types' of incoming events, and I want to dispatch them to different IObservables, exposed as properties, but without subscribing multiple times to the underlying UDP.

```
public IObservable<TimeEvent> TimeEventChannel { get; private set; }
public IObservable<SpaceEvent> SpaceEventChannel { get; private set; }

Subject<TimeEvent> _TimeSubject = new Subject<TimeEvent>();
Subject<SpaceEvent> _SpaceSubject = new Subject<SpaceEvent>();

public EventDispatcher(IChannelListener listener)
{
    TimeEventChannel = _TimeSubject;
    SpaceEventChannel = _SpaceSubject;
    listener.Data.Subscribe(SwitchEvent);
}

private void SwitchEvent(AbstractEvent e)
{
    switch(e.EventType)
    {
        case EEventType.Time: _TimeSubject.OnNext(e as TimeEvent); break;
        case EEventType.Space: _SpaceSubject.OnNext(e as SpaceEvent); break;
    }
}
```

(`listener.Data` is an `IObservable<AbstractEvent>`).

The problem I'm having is trying to work out how to test this in isolation (without hooking up to UDP)

```
var spaceEvent = new SpaceEvent();
var udpSubject = new Subject<AbstractEvent>();
var mock = new Mock<IChannelListener>();
mock.SetupGet(listener => listener.Data).Returns(udpSubject);
var dispatcher = new EventDispatcher(mock.Object);

subject.OnNext(spaceEvent);
var result = dispatcher.SpaceEventChannel.SingleOrDefault();
```

As it stands, the test blocks on the last line, and I'm pretty sure it's because there's something I've fundamentally not grokked about how `Subject` works.

Question: What am I thinking wrong? How should I go about testing this particular use case? Am I implementing the Dispatcher backwards too?

---

Just in case, this is what the real `ChannelListener` currently looks like:

```
public ChannelListener(UdpClient udpClient, FrameInterpreter frameInterpreter)
{
    Data = Observable.Defer(() => 
    {
        IPEndPoint ep = null;
        return Observable.FromAsyncPattern<byte[]>(
                    udpClient.BeginReceive,
                    i => udpClient.EndReceive(i, ref ep)
                )()
                .Select(bytes => frameInterpreter.ParseFrame(bytes));
    });
}

public IObservable<AbstractEvent> Data { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Is this line `mock.SetupGet(listener => listener.Data).Returns(subject);` meant to actually use `udpSubject` at the end there?

Comment: @yamen, well spotted. An artefact of trying to create a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Comment: Which is really the most noble reason for any mistake on SO!

Comment: Not sure it applies to your situation, but have you considered using the testing framework in `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing`? It allows you to virtualize time and do assertions on observable sequences.

Comment: @MartinLiversage, yeah, I'm vaguely aware that it exists. I watched the video with Wes and Bart (IIRC) months ago and had my brains duly scrambled :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the lines:

```
subject.OnNext(spaceEvent);
var result = dispatcher.SpaceEventChannel.SingleOrDefault();
```

Try replacing it with:

```
AbstractEvent result = null;
dispatcher.SpaceEventChannels.Subscribe(e => result = e);
subject.OnNext(spaceEvent);
// ...
```

The problem is that when you call subject.OnNext, it runs thru the "pipeline" * immediately*. Therefore, the next line's SingleOrDefault actually locks the text, because no value ever "arrives" to it.

Comment: Yes, that's the secondary issue. The `IDisposable` problem is the first one since `SpaceEventChannels` wasn't receiving anything. In general, we set up subscriptions first and then push values through second (for hot observables such as this one).

Comment: Yes! That's it. I was homing in on those lines of code, but hadn't worked out that particular combination!

Comment: @yamen The IDisposable problem you are discussing is non-existent. The Dispose method does not get called automatically (unless it's in a using block).

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue you have is simple. This line:

```
listener.Data.Subscribe(SwitchEvent);
```

Returns an `IDisposable`. Which immediately goes out of scope and is disposed. So `SwitchEvent` never fires. You just need to hold that `IDisposable` in an instance variable in the `EventDispatcher` class.

```
private IDisposable _subscription;

public EventDispatcher(IChannelListener listener)
{
    TimeEventChannel = _TimeSubject;
    SpaceEventChannel = _SpaceSubject;
    _subscription = listener.Data.Subscribe(SwitchEvent);
}
```

I would also seriously consider changing `EventDispatcher` to accept an `IObservable<AbstractEvent>` rather than `IChannelListener` if that's all it really needs. You can imagine how much easier this would be to test too!

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that right away. Concerning your last remark, this is a side effect of thinking in 'classes first'. I've noticed that with Rx, most of the things that I thought would need a lot of code actually do end up just being a function. Have you got any advice/comments about my transformation of udp into IObservable? (pinched from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4433727/11410))

Comment: Looks great to me! I tend to think functionally however and hence shy away from the added class plus property. You can have a class to wrap the UDP stuff, but you don't need to pass that whole class to `EventDispatcher` - only the `IObservable` interface. Basically, passing the lowest functionality interface needed.

Comment: Note this could be as simple as changing this: `new EventDispatcher(channel);` to this: `new EventDispatcher(channel.Data);` in real code, and not using mocks in the test.

Comment: Gave Dave the tick, as that was the last link in the chain. Hope you don't mind...

Comment: No worries! Although he made the same `IDisposable` mistake in his answer which means mine was more subtle :-). "The primary issue you have is simple"... Glad to see another RX convert, welcome aboard.

Comment: yamen, I don't think that this is correct. The IDisposables returned by Rx don't override Finalize, so Dipose won't be called by the GC.

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like I need to investigate! Thanks for the heads up.